# Keycloak - all created users have admin Effective Role

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to create a user in Keycloak admin console, but it has effective roles that should not be there. In addition to default realm roles, each user, when created, has odd Effective Roles. And I can't understand, where they come from. Even when I delete all assigned roles, effective roles just stay there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not happen usually, seems like a problem with your Keycloak setup and installation.

Have you checked the default roles at realm level? Roles shown in screenshot belong to realm-management client.
If you are using master realm, I'd suggest you to create a new realm other than master and use it.